# react-native-iap just hangs on ios trying to get subscriptions on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-iap

The following component functions nominally under Android. We thought we were cool.

But, the same code on iOS hangs when it tries to get subscriptions. The request doesn't succeed, doesn't fail, doesn't crash. The JS promise is seemingly never resolved or rejected.

Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas on what I should try next?

This is running on my 100% real iPhone logged into my Apple account tethered to my MacBook Pro. There don't appear to be any other issues regarding this phone's ability to make purchases.

##### Logs

```
 LOG  [Subscription] Will init connection
 LOG  [Subscription] Did init connection
 LOG  [Subscription] Will clear transaction ios
 LOG  [Subscription] Did clear transaction ios
 LOG  [Subscription] Will get subscription
 ...then nothing, I've waited over 5 minutes...
```

##### Component JSX

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react-native";
import * as RNIap from "react-native-iap";
import { Subscription, SubscriptionPurchase } from "react-native-iap/src/types";
import { SUBSCRIPTION_ID } from "../env";

class SubscriptionScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    subscription: undefined,
    available: undefined,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      console.log('[Subscription]','Will init connection');
      await RNIap.initConnection();
      console.log('[Subscription]','Did init connection');
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        console.log('[Subscription]','Will clear transaction ios');
        await RNIap.clearTransactionIOS();
        console.log('[Subscription]','Did clear transaction ios');
      }
      console.log('[Subscription]','Will get subscription');
      const subscription: Subscription = (await RNIap.getSubscriptions([SUBSCRIPTION_ID])).find(s => s.productId === SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
      console.log('[Subscription]','Did get subscription', subscription);
      console.log('[Subscription]','Will get available');
      const available: SubscriptionPurchase = (await RNIap.getAvailablePurchases([SUBSCRIPTION_ID])).find(p => p.productId === SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
      console.log('[Subscription]','Did get available', available);
      this.setState({subscription, available});

    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to get subscriptions!', err.code, err.message);
      Sentry.captureException(err);
    }
  }

  async componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('[Subscription]','Will close connection');
    await RNIap.endConnection();
    console.log('[Subscription]','Did close connection');
  }

  async purchaseSubscription() {
    try {
      await RNIap.requestSubscription(SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to purchase subscriptions!', err.code, err.message);
      Sentry.captureException(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.available)
      return (
        <Text>You're a subscriber!</Text>
      )
    else
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.purchaseSubscription} >
          <Text>Subscribe</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
  }
}

export default SubscriptionScreen;
```

##### Dependencies

```json
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.3",
"react-native-iap": "^8.0.0-rc.6",
```

##### GitHub

Also posted this to https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/1708

Comment: Upgrading from `react-native-iap@8.0.0-rc.6` to `8.0.10` resolved this issue.